# [i].val is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
var arrayPost = $("#formPlano13").serializeArray();
var arrayCBDDD = $("#formPlano13 input[name='cbDDD[]']").serializeArray();
var trDDD = '';

// *  Geramos um loop para os DDDs escolhidos
$.each(arrayCBDDD, function(k, v){

    qtdDDD = $('input[name=txQtdDDD' + v.value + ']').val();
    qtdPortabilidade = $('input[name=txQtdPortabilidadeDDD' + v.value + ']').val();
    trDDD += '<tr><td><strong>DDD ' + v.value + '</strong><br />Qtd Números: ' + qtdDDD + '<br /></td><td>R$</td></tr>';

    if(qtdPortabilidade > 0){

        trDDD += '<tr><td><strong>Portabilidade DDD ' + v.value + ':</strong><br />';
        varNumero = $('input[name=\'txPortabilidadeNumero' + v.value + '[]\']');

        for(i = 0; i < varNumero.length; i++){
            trDDD += '- ' + varNumero[i].val() + '<br>';
        }

        trDDD += '</td></tr>';

    }

});

console.log(arrayPost);
console.log(trDDD);
```

**Valores de arrayPost (podem aumentar ou diminuir dinamicamente)**

```
0: {name: "cbDDD[]", value: "011"}
1: {name: "txQtdDDD011", value: "1"}
2: {name: "cbPortabilidade011", value: "on"}
3: {name: "txQtdPortabilidadeDDD011", value: "1"}
4: {name: "txPortabilidadeNumero011[]", value: "(11) 11111-1111"}
```

**Valores de arrayCBDDD  (podem aumentar ou diminuir dinamicamente)**

```
0: {name: "cbDDD[]", value: "011"}
```

Ao executá-lo, estou recebendo o erro: 
**$(...)[i].val is not a function**

Como posso capturar o valor do varNumero que vem deste loop? Estou tendo problemas pois esse input é um array multiplo (pode receber diversos valores).

Comment: Acho que o que procuras é `varNumero.eq(i).val()` ou `varNumero[i].value`. Podes testar?

Comment: `varNumero[i]` vai retornar um elemento html, que não possui a função `.val()`. Nesse caso, você pode acessar com `.value`, ou, se quiser continuar com o objeto `jquery`, use `.eq(i)`

Comment: @Sergio sempre mais rápido que eu haha :)

Comment: @ArturoTemplário :)

Comment: Vou testar e já retorno! :D

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Sei que parece idiota o que perguntarei, mas como faço para marcar sua resposta, @Sergio como respondida?

Comment: @MaykelEsser a pergunta é bem comum. Eu já marquei como duplicada de outra pergunta anterior. Não precisas de fazer mais nada :)

Comment: Muito obrigado! ;-)